# Get last modification date on many SVN repos

Tags: centos, bash, svn

I'm hosting svn server for my developers. From server I see all configured dirs with svn repos. I want to get last modification date on all of them(obout 30 different projects). I don't want to connect to all of them make checkout and then with svn command on each check last modification. I want use only bash to extract that info but have no idea how and even is it possible in that way.

EDIT1:
it looks like this that a have for example 10 project in different repos on the same server (no branches)... all project sits in one directory configured as different svn repos:

```
/svn_repos/project1

/svn_repos/project2

/svn_repos/project3

...

/svn_repos/project10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svnlook tree --full-paths "$REPO" | grep '/branches/[^/]*/$' | \
while read branch ; do
    svnlook history -l 1 "$REPO" "$branch"
done | while read revision path ; do
    # Input looks like the following, in a loop...
    #
    # REVISION   PATH
    # --------   ----
    #       20   /path/to/branch
    case "$revision" in
      REVISION|--------) : ;;  # Skip headers
      *) echo "$path" `svnlook date -r "$revision" "$REPO"`
         ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Nice script but it does not work in my case...there is no branches in any of my repos ...

Comment: Then it's even easier.  Just use `svnlook date "$REPO"`.

Answer (score 1):

try the below command

```
bash$> svnlook date <repo_path>
```